# Solving scrabble lab task from cs50 without using isalpha, ascii codes and strlen

Tags: c, cs50

The task details can be found here -->  https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/labs/2/

How to solve this task without using isalpha and (-'A' or - 65) and strlen?

Please do not use anything related to ascii codes or any other closely relation functions of `isalpha()` and `strlen()`.

Below is the current solution using isalpha and (-'A' or - 65 ) and `strlen()`.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
  // Get input words from both players
  string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
  string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

  // Score both words
  int score1 = compute_score(word1);
  int score2 = compute_score(word2);

  // TODO: Print the winner
  if (score1 > score2)
  {
    printf("Player 1 wins!");
  }
  else  if (score1 < score2)
  {
    printf("Player 2 wins!");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Tie!");
  }

}

int compute_score(string word)
{
  int score = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
  {
    //if word typed is alphabetical
    if (isalpha(word[i]))
    {
      //concert lower or uppercase to uppercase , this works the same even if used tolower but need to change A to a to get the position for POINTS array
      int get_position = toupper(word[i]) - 'A';
      score = score + POINTS[get_position];
    }

  }
  return score;

}
```

Comment: `"please do not use anything related to ascii codes"` -- It is impossible to do any kind of character handling in C without working with ASCII codes (unless your compiler is using a non-ASCII character set). For example, whenever you use a [character constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant), it gets translated to the corresponding ASCII code.

Comment: If you don't do a lot of additional explaining my bet is on "impossible"; which I would reflect as a "not reproducible" close-vote in a few hours. E.g. explain what makes you think that it is possible with the very restrictive rules you have added on top of the referenced exercise page.

Comment: This requires significant elaboration. The `strlen` is easy to toss. If the rest of this nonsense means you can't utilize "ascii codes" as magic number immediate values, nor character literals of any kind, it is still plausible, but unnecessarily tedious and brittle. Regardless, this is going nowhere without significant elaboration on your part. Start explaining or this is headed to the great closure abyss.

Comment: The hints in the problem description include "Recall that computers represent characters using ASCII, a standard that represents each character as a number."  Notwithstanding that that's an oversimplification, how is it, then, that you think you're not supposed to use anything related to ASCII?

Comment: The restrictions you list are not specified in the problem description. Did you think of them yourself or or are you misreading it?

Comment: You *can* convert a character to an integer using the `strtol` function, e.g. `char str[2] = {word[i]}; int num = strtol(str, endptr, 36) - 10;`  But the error checking needed to duplicate what `isalpha` does is a bit onerous.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel "without using  ascii codes ..." would mean not to assume `'A' == 65`, etc.  Yes, user code does get translated ubiquitously from ASCII text, yet user code does not need to assume ASCII encoding to solve this task.  Only assumption needed is that the encoding language and user encoding are the same.

Comment: @user3386109 No need for [`- 10`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637562/solving-scrabble-lab-task-from-cs50-without-using-isalpha-ascii-codes-and-strle/70637885#comment124871626_70637562) nor a separate variable `str`.  e.g. `int num = strtol((char[]){word[i], 0}, NULL, 36);`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookup table.  Code is **not** dependent on ASCII nor 2's complement.  Works in [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) too.

```
int compute_score(string word) {
  // Let OP fill out the table.
  // Use 256 or or UCHAR_MAX + 1 or ((unsigned char) -1) + 1
  const unsigned char value[256] = { //
      ['A'] = 1, ['B'] = 3, ['C'] = 3, /* ... */ ['Z'] = 10, //
      ['a'] = 1, ['b'] = 3, ['c'] = 3, /* ... */ ['z'] = 10};
  int score = 0;
  while (*word) {
    score += value[*(unsigned char*) word];
    word++;
  }
  return score;
}
```

If code *must* use `int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, ...`, then initialize with `['Z'] = POINTS[25]`, etc.